# Featured listing

Tags: 7, nodes

How can we create featured contents in drupal 7 for a specific content type?

I have a content type called "Properties" with various fields to add real estate properties.I added a number of properties in this content type.

In the home page of the website, i have a region to show "Featured Properties".
In this region i need to show 3 properties.[ an image and the title of each node,which is set as featured].

My question is :

1. How can i set some nodes in a specific content type as featured from admin side?
2. How can we show that featured contents at the user side as blocks or any other way?

Comment: where do you want to display featured content?

Comment: i want to display the featured content at home page(page--front.tpl.php).

Comment: i mean, do you want to display it inside your content, or like a block...

Comment: yes i need to display it as a separate section ,not in content. show like a block.

Comment: please provide more information about featured content, do you want to show 3-4 random content or how do you want to select featured content to display(e.g. which nodes you need to show)

Comment: i edited my question and added more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this in different ways. I think the best way for you will be next:

Add additional field to your content type `Properties` -> for example `featured` interger value. Next you will need to install [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, this module is really strong and awesome, you can display any content you want in block or any aother way.

Then go to `Structure` -> `Views` -> `Add new view` , and create new view, chose `Create a block` instead of creating page, set title and description, `Display format` - chose what you need or prefer( i suggest to use unformatted list) of  `fields` - > *Save and continue*.

Next you will need to add `FIELDS` you want to display, click `add` and chose -> `Content: Image` and `Content: Title` there are different settings for this fields(uncheck Create a label). Next click on `ADVANCED` and click add a `Contextual filter` and chose your field you have created for your node - `Content: featured` (or any other name you have chosen when created your field in node). Click on it and in `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE` - and in `Provide default value` chose `fixed value` and set it `1,2,3` comma separated.

Save and your view is done, now go to `Structure` -> `blocks` and add your view to your region you need.

In your nodes which you want to display in field `featured` add `1` to - display first `2` second, `3` to display third. Now you can manage what nodes to display as featured.

Oh i forgot, in your view `SORT CRITERIA` - chose  `Content: featured`.

Also you can do this with [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module, but i don't have much time right now  to  explain.

Good luck.

Comment: Great help! thank you for the detailed reply.let me try this..... :)

Comment: ask here, if you have any questions about it.